# how to apply css3 to pseudo-elements in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, pseudo-element

I'm currently working on a project where I use these two libraries: [ie7-js](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) and [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/)

Unfortunately, I'm not able to apply CSS3 (gradient or border-radius) to pseudo-elements like `:before` and `:after` neither in IE7 nor IE8.

Does anybody have an idea how could I accomplish that?

Comment: for some reason it works in IE7, but not in ie8

Comment: Not the best thing to do by any means but you can force IE8 to run as IE7. Not suggesting to do it but if you're stuck it might help you out.

Comment: another note: IE8 applies styles to the whole element instead to the :before pseudo-element, ie: h2:before { ... } causes h2 to look as defined in h2:before... strange!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE7 does not support `:before` and `:after` generated content, so the content itself is emulated using a combination of the VML DOM and the HTML DOM, then CSS3 emulation is applied on those elements using DHTML filters and transitions behind the scenes using ie7.js and css3pie. IE8 does support `:before` and `:after` generated content, but ironically this breaks the CSS3 emulation layer, because [generated content has no DOM of its own](https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues/189) and there is no [shadow DOM](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/). Use conditional comments to create duplicates of the `:before` and `:after` content for IE8 only, position them to match their location in IE7, then apply the css3pie effects on them instead.